# get key value from array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I have array data in this format , i want to get key and value array.
how can be get key and value from this array in  javascript .

```
jsonData =  [
    {"dimensions":[5.9,3.9,4.4,3.1,4.8],"icon":0,"curves":  [false,false,false,false,false],"id":"p1","color":"0x000000"},
    {"dimensions":[5.9,3.9,4.4,3.1,4.8],"icon":0,"curves":  [false,false,false,false,false],"id":"p1","color":"0x000000"},
    {"dimensions":[5.9,3.9,4.4,3.1,4.8],"icon":0,"curves":  [false,false,false,false,false],"id":"p1","color":"0x000000"}
];
```

Comment: Sorry to be blunt here, but what's the problem? JSON format IS an array.

Comment: hi thedixon i want to convert this data into array cause we neet to pass data into array format

Comment: that json data is ALREADY a javascript array.

Comment: That isn't JSON, the `jsonData =  ` makes it JavaScript. The `[]` makes it an array. You already have a JavaScript array. So to echo thedixon, what is the problem?

Comment: But this is an array format, in JavaScript - "jsonData" is your array. Is it because you don't know how to manipulate this array for your needs?

Comment: thedixon i understand please give me answer for this

Comment: @mohit: We still don't know what the problem is though! Please explain what *result* you want. The more information you provide, the easier it is for us to help you.

Comment: @Felix Kling i want to store key  and value in array, means dimensions is key and value =  5.9,3.9,4.4,3.1,4.8 like all same

Comment: @mohitgupta — The code in the question *already does that*! (Except that having named keys in an array doesn't make sense, but you've got that in an object and that object is in an array)

Comment: @mohit: If you understand it, is the problem solved then? Because we don't understand. Anyways, I'm referring you to this question now: http://stackoverflow.com/q/11922383/218196.

Comment: @Felix Kling  i have change my code you look at now now problem is how to store in array

Comment: @mohitgupta — Now you have changed your code … it is **still** stored in an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATED**: Added `eval`. Hadn't noticed that it was in a string.

It seems to me that your biggest problem is that it is all wrapped in an array with a single element. You can do:

```
var element = eval(jsonData)[0];
```

The `eval` is there to convert from string to a javascript object.
Then, to access anything (for example the `dimensions` array), do the following:

```
var dimensions = element.dimensions;
```

Comment: dimensions only return single "[" if we alert(dimensions) this

Comment: My bad - I didn't see that the data was in a string. I have updated the answer to take this into account.

Answer (score 2):

I have implement this solution

```
function getDataArray(name='', index=''){ 
   elements = generateDataArray("profiles");
   arrData = $.parseJSON(elements);  
   data = new Array();
   color = new Array();
   dataid = new Array();
   $.each(arrData,function(key,val){
       $.each(val,function(key2,val2){
     if(key2=="dimensions"){      
       data.push(val2)
      }else if(key2=="color"){
       color.push(val2)
       }

    })
    })

    number =0;
    newArray = new Array();
    while(number<data.length){
    newArray[number] = new Array(data[number],color[number])
    number++;
   }

      return newArray;
 }
```